# Django OneToOneField Unique fails when extending User model

Tags: python, django, relationships

I'm trying to extends Django User model by means of an Actor model but I'm getting some problems.

There is my code:

```
class Actor(models.Model):
    usuario = models.OneToOneField('auth.User', unique = True, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.usuario.get_full_name() + ' (' + self.usuario.get_username() + ')'
```

The problem is that one-to-one relationship is not unique so I can create two differents actors and relate them with the same user.

Use case idea: I create a User (User model by Django) then I create an actor and relate him with the user I created before. If I create a second actor, there would not must be posible related him with the same user.

Comment: _The problem is that one-to-one relationship is not unique so I can create two differents actors_ Then, don't user a One-To-One relation, this is exactly what it is meant for.

Comment: _Two differents Actors (or more) related with the same User_ when I'm trying to restrict the relation to one-to-one (an user is only related with an actor and viceversa).

Comment: That is what a one-to-one relationship is. It *is* unique, and you *can't* relate an actor to more than one user. What makes you think you can?

Comment: @DanielRoseman that's Ok but I also want to achieve that an user can't be related with more than an actor.

Comment: Yes. That is why it is a **one**-to-**one** relationship. Both sides are unique.

Comment: @DanielRoseman but the problem is that an **user** can be related with more than an **actor** (not viceversa: _an actor -> an user_). I want one-to-one in both directions.

Comment: For the third time. **That is precisely what a one-to-one relationship is**. A user **cannot** be related with more than one actor.

Comment: The problem is that in my application, an user **can** be related with more than one actor. This is the reason of the issue. One-to-one relationship is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `ForeignKey` with `unique=True`.

Comment: I have tried but It has the same behaviour that one-to-one relationship: an user can be related with more than one actor.